# How to free memory with move constructor

Tags: c++

I am trying to create my own vector and here is a minimal example to introduce the problem I have:

```
class DemoVector {
public:
    DemoVector() : capacity_(1), size_(0) {
        data_ = new int[1];
    }

    DemoVector(DemoVector&& rhs) {
        data_ = std::move(rhs.data_);
        size_ = rhs.size_;
        capacity_ = rhs.capacity_;
    }

    ~DemoVector() {
        delete[] data_;
    }

    void PushBack(const int &v) {
        // doesn't matter
    }

private:
    int *data_;
    size_t capacity_;
    size_t size_;
};
```

Test:

```
TEST_CASE("Test") {
    DemoVector b;
    b.PushBack(1);
    DemoVector c(std::move(b));
}
```

I have a problem here and I understand why. I have two objects which points on the same memory. Second destructor tries to free memory, which have already been freed by first destructor.

But I don't know how to fix it.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is a reason the moved-from object is not `const` in the move constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `std::move` is basically just a cast that doesn't actually move anything! You need to update the values in the other object yourself:

```
DemoVector(DemoVector&& rhs) {
    data_ = rhs.data_;
    size_ = rhs.size_;
    capacity_ = rhs.capacity_;
    rhs.data_ = nullptr;
    rhs.size_ = 0;
    rhs.capacity = 0;
}
```

Or alternatively to make use of the existing constructor:

```
DemoVector(DemoVector&& rhs): DemoVector() {
    // Or write your own swap function to reuse this elsewhere
    std::swap(data_, rhs.data_);
    std::swap(size_, rhs.size_);
    std::swap(capacity_, rhs.capacity_);
}
```

It's up to you how you want users of your class to handle moved-from objects. In the second case, and possibly also the first depending on how the rest of your class works, `rhs` (`b` in your test case) will be an empty vector.

Comment: Note about the choice between the implementations: Swapping is marginally slower than assigning null, but it is quite useful for establishing a class invariant of `data_` never being null which can allow removal of null checks in many places.

Answer (score 3):

`std::move(rhs.data_)` doesn't actually move anything. `std::move` is nothing more than a named *cast*. It produces an rvalue reference that *allows* move semantics to occur. But for primitive types, it's just a copy operation. The pointer is being copied, and so you end up with two pointers that contain the same address. Since you don't want the source object to still be pointing at the the same buffer, simply modify it. That's why move-semantics is build around non-const references.

Move constructors are commonplace now, so there's a standard utility (C++14) to help write them in a way that makes code behave more as you'd expect. It's [`std::exchange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange). You can simply write

```
DemoVector(DemoVector&& rhs)
  : data_(std::exchange(rhs.data_, nullptr))
  , size_(std::exchange(rhs.size_ , 0))
  , capacity_(std::exchange(rhs.capacity_ , 0))
{}
```

And all the values get adjusted properly. `std::exchange` modifies its first argument to hold the value of the second argument. And finally, it return the old value of the first argument. Very handy to shift values around in one-liner initializations.